# netbeans 7-8, inject of remote ejb

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb

Hi, I have an EJB project called "service-ejb" with this:

```java
@Stateless
@Remote(ServiceRemote.class)
public class Services implements ServiceLocal, ServiceRemote {
  [...business code...]
}
```

the I have the local interface, in the same project:

```java
@Local
public interface ServiceLocal { }
```

and the remote interface, in a class library project called "service-lib":

```java
@Remote
public interface ServiceRemote {
  public boolean checkIfOk();
}
```

I can deploy it without problem, alone or in a java EE application. The point is that I don't understand how to tell NetBeans that I wish to call that beans from another application. For example I have another java EE project with a war component, where inside a servlet I wrote:

```java
@EJB
private ServiceRemote serviceTest;
```

but of course it will fail compiling, so I tried with:

```java
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
ServiceRemote serviceTest = (ServiceRemote) ic.lookup("ServiceRemote");
```

with no luck... Where in NetBeans I can tell it to use the "service-lib" as a reference? I don't want it to be added as library and then deployed with the ear, I only want NetBeans to compile correctly the code.

Sorry if the question sound silly, but I've read the documentation and I don't understant what I'm missing...

**--- edit ---**

I'll try to be more clear. "service-ejb" reference "service-lib", so I've deployed "service-ejb" to glassfish. Correctly, I have:

```java
glassfish_applications_directory $ find -name "service*"
./__internal/service-ejb
./__internal/service-ejb/service-ejb.jar
./service-ejb
./service-ejb/com/tecytal/components/email/beans/Service.class
./service-ejb/com/tecytal/components/email/interfaces/local/ServiceLocal.class
./service-ejb/service-lib.jar
```

Then I open a java EE project, let's call it "myEngine" with a war module "myEngine-war". I've tried to add to "myEngine-war" a reference to "service-lib", of course, and in this case it compile well. The point is that I can do everything, tell to netbeans NOT to package the "service-lib" with the war, but when I deploy "myEngine" I get:

```java
glassfish_applications_directory $ find -name "service*"
./myEngine/lib/service-lib.jar
./__internal/service-ejb
./__internal/service-ejb/service-ejb.jar
./service-ejb
./service-ejb/com/tecytal/components/email/beans/Service.class
./service-ejb/com/tecytal/components/email/interfaces/local/ServiceLocal.class
./service-ejb/service-lib.jar
```

I DON'T want to have TWO service-lib.jar in my server, one in the service-ejb and one in myEngine, I don't understand how I can use a remote ebj in netbeans telling to him NOT TO deploy the same lib 3214899213 times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to add the remote service interface and all classes it references (including exceptions) in a separate jar. Then in the other 2 projects declare a dependcy to this jar.

```
I don't want it to be added as library and then deployed with the ear
```

I recommed to add only the service-lib contain the interface etc as a library and deploy it with the ear, not the whole service-ejb containing the implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. 
The service-lib contains remote interfaces and all the needed classes (transports, etc), I've tried adding the service-lib project to the client application (with package option activated and not), but deployment always fail with "zip file is empty -- invalid zip file ... service-lib.jar".
What's the point of having the possibility of calling a remote ejb if I have to package it in my project

Comment: Only package the remote interface etc, not the implementation.

Comment: so, I misunderstood something: to call remotely an ejb I have to package the remote interface yes or yes, so if I have 100 application that use "service" I will have 100 copies of the service remote interface, it's right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, AFAIK (I haven't called yet a remote EJB from another Java EE application.) Just make sure the remote interface (along with DTOs, Exceptions etc.) are in a separate jar, so you can simply package the whole jar in your EAR/ WAR file.